# Python documentation equivalent for Perl's "perldoc"

Tags: python, documentation, pydoc

### Quick [perldoc](http://search.cpan.org/~dapm/perl-5.14.4/pod/perldoc.pod) overview:

When writing a Perl module you can document it with [`POD`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html) style documentation.  Then to get an overview of how the module works you can just type this into the command line:

`perldoc <module_name>`

---

### How do I do this with Python?

I understand that Python has a standard form of documenting code using "docstrings" that is somewhat similar to Perl's POD style.  The information about the Python module can then be extracted using the `help()` function, but this is *far from elegant*.

First you need to start the Python interpreter, then import the module you want to get help for, and then finally you can use the `help()` function to get information about the module.

**example:**

```
>python
# Prints Python version info
>>>import <module_name>
>>>help(<module_name>)
# Prints documentation!
```

---

### Is there a better way?

I would like a Python equivalent to the way this works for Perl:

`pydoc <module_name>`

but when I try this I get the following output:

```
'pydoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: `pydoc` is the command to use. If that is missing, there is likely a problem with your Python installation.

Comment: So your saying that it should work just like `perldoc`?

Comment: Essentially; they both extract documentation from the requested object (`pydoc` via definitions and docstrings, `perldoc` via embedded `pod` documentation).

Comment: Example: pydoc3 pathlib.Path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It turns out that `pydoc` actually does work just like `perldoc`!

With a catch ... you just need to type it a little different!

`python -m pydoc <module_name>`

---

### And with a little "haquery"... :)

Create a pydoc.bat file as shown below.

pydoc.bat:

```
python -m pydoc %1
```

Then store this file in "C:\Python27" (or in the same location as your python.exe file)

> Then swiftly wave your hands over the keyboard and exclaim "***SIM SALA BIM!***"

your `pydoc` command will now work!

`pydoc <module_name>`

Answer (score 0):

Install and use [IPython](http://ipython.org/). It allows you to type `<object>?` and get information about that object. You can also type `.`+`TAB` to get attributes for an object. There are many, many more wonderful features to IPython, I highly recommend you check it out.

Answer (score -1):

Python Document Strings are stored in the **doc** variable.  You can look at that variable for information:
`print( int().__doc__)`

Returns the following:
int(x[, base]) -> integer

Convert a string or number to an integer, if possible.  A floating point
argument will be truncated towards zero (this does not include a string
representation of a floating point number!)  When converting a string, use
the optional base.  It is an error to supply a base when converting a
non-string.  If base is zero, the proper base is guessed based on the
string content.  If the argument is outside the integer range a
long object will be returned instead.

Comment: I understand that, but thats still not very pretty or efficient.  You still need to be inside the Python interpreter to use that and the format is HIDEOUS for anyone unfamiliar with Python.  I want something I can tell a user who has never used Python before to type in the windows cmd prompt and have it give them the documentation about how to use the module they want.  `perldoc` does this very well for Perl